# Directing links to a DIV

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I apologize in advance if this is answered somewhere but I've tried looking and found *nothing* (I think it's the way I'm wording it, I'm not sure how...) but basically how links are directed to an 'iframe'-I want mine directed to a DIV instead, is this possible? If so, how?  I've tried a few ways that I *thought* would work but have failed...

The site is [here](https://zaarathefairy.tumblr.com/commissions) and I basically want the links info to go into the black div box when clicked.

My code:

```css
body{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

#container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#mainbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 135px;
}

#title{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    position:fixed;
    top: 105px;
    color: #e8c8c5;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    border-color: #e8c8c5;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #e8c8c5;

}

#content{
    background-color: black;
    width: 860px;
    height: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>  
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">Commissions;</div>
      <div id="mainbox">
       <ul class="nav">
         <!--nav starts here -->
        <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="/work/">Examples</a></li>
        <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Faq</a></li>
      </ul>   
        <!-- nav ends here -->    

      <div id="content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the information in, say, the about page, to be inserted into the div with an id of content? So the user never actually leaves the page, instead the content inside the content div just changes with each navigation click?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad explanation but you got it.

Comment: No worries, you probably would be better off using AJAX to do this to make the request and insert just the content you want into the content div, the other option would be you have all your content on the one page and wrap each content block in an id and then hide and show the div you want, but you'd still need Javascript to determine the link clicked. This might help you http://api.jquery.com/load/